# Interface type cannot be statically allocated into a method with two variables

Tags: objective-c

I have this code, who pick the variables that exist within the method, and put they inside a NSString:

```
- (void)selecionaListaDBs:(NSString *)valores tabela:(NSString *)nomeTB{

    NSString *querySQL = @"SELECT %@ FROM %@",valores,nomeTB;
}
```

But I'm receiving a message that:

> Interface type cannot be statically allocated

I am a beginner, and this is the first time that happens to me, someone could help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax :

```
@"SELECT %@ FROM %@",valores,nomeTB;
```

is incorrect. The compiler does not replace the variables automatically for you.

One way to replace the variables in the query string will be :

```
NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT %@ FROM %@",valores,nomeTB];
```